# Configure local proxy for the npm audit with Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, nexus3, npm-audit

Based on this one https://github.com/chovyy/npm-audit-proxy

In this case
Nexus OSS v3 manager running behind Apache reverse proxy.
There is need to proxy npm audit as well from  https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/.

So how to configure properly Apache to pass npm adit call to
https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/

Answer (score 1):

This Apache configuration worked in my case.

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
  ServerName nexus.corporate.domain

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1.2
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On
  SSLCompression off
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/nexus/nexus.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/nexus/nexus.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/nexus/Local_Corporate_CA_chain.crt

  SSLSessionTickets   off
  SSLProxyEngine On

  ProxyPass /repository/npm-public/-/npm/v1/security/audits https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits
  ProxyPassReverse /repository/npm-public/-/npm/v1/security/audits https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits
  ProxyPass         /  http://127.0.0.1:8081/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse  /  http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyRequests     Off
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  AllowEncodedSlashes on

  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

  <Proxy http://127.0.0.1:8081/*>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/nexus_apache_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/nexus_apache_access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

I had error Forbidde 403 but it was caused by **ProxyPreserveHost on**.
Changed it to **ProxyPreserveHost off**

**/repository/npm-public/** is npm group type repository created in nexus.
https://nexus.corporate.domain/repository/npm-public/

Answer (score 0):

From npm 9 on (lockfileVersion: 3), you also have to proxy `https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories`. A minimal configuration, that is working for me:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName npm.customdomain.com

        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        SSLProxyEngine On

        ProxyPass /repository/npm-public/-/npm/v1/security/audits        https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits
        ProxyPass /repository/npm-public/-/npm/v1/security/advisories    https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories

        SSLEngine on
        # Your SSL, Log and further configurations...
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```